# react-router Link to post.id, keep post_index on the dom

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-router

Screenshot:

[image: screenshot]

When I click on my link from index_page.

```
<Link className="btn btn-info" to={`/posts/${post.id}`}>Show</Link>
```

The click works well, but my post.id loads below my index. Why my index is still on the DOM? I did something wrong with my router?

**index.js**

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
import { createStore, applyMiddleware } from 'redux';
import { browserHistory, HashRouter, BrowserRouter, Route, Switch } from 'react-router-dom';
import promise from 'redux-promise';

import reducers from './reducers';
import PostsShow from './components/posts_show';
import PostsIndex from './components/posts_index';

const createStoreWithMiddleware = applyMiddleware(promise)(createStore);

ReactDOM.render(
  <Provider store={createStoreWithMiddleware(reducers)}>
    <BrowserRouter >
      <div>
        <Route path="/" component={PostsIndex} />
        <Route path="/posts/:id" component={PostsShow} />
      </div>
    </BrowserRouter>
  </Provider>
  , document.querySelector('.app'));
```

**post_index.js**

```
class PostsIndex extends Component {
  componentDidMount() {
    this.props.fetchPosts();
  }

  onDeleteClick(id) {
    this.props.deletePost(id, () => {
      this.props.history.push('/');
    });
  }

  renderPosts() {
    return _.map(this.props.posts, post => {
      return (
        <tr key={post.id}>
          <td>{post.thumb_url}</td>
          <td>{post.id}</td>
          <td>{post.title}</td>
          <td>{post.slug}</td>
          <td>{post.created_at}</td>
          <td>{post.update_at}</td>
          <td>
            <Link className="btn btn-info" to={`/posts/${post.id}`}>Show</Link>
            <button className="btn btn-danger" onClick={this.onDeleteClick.bind(this, post.id)}>Delete</button>
          </td>
        </tr>
      );
    });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <h3>Posts</h3>
        <table className="table table-condensed">
          <thead>
            <tr>
              <th>thumb</th>
              <th>id</th>
              <th>title</th>
              <th>slug</th>
              <th>created_at</th>
              <th>update_at</th>
              <th width="10%">action</th>
            </tr>
          </thead>
          <tbody>
            {this.renderPosts()}
          </tbody>
        </table>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

function mapStateToProps(state) {
  return { posts: state.posts };
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, { fetchPosts, deletePost})(PostsIndex);
```

**post_show.js**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';
import { fetchPost } from '../actions';

class PostsShow extends Component {
  componentDidMount() {
    const { id } = this.props.match.params;
    this.props.fetchPost(id);
  }

  render() {
    const { post } = this.props;

    if (!post) {
      return <div>Loading...</div>;
    }

    return (
      <div>
        <br />
        <Link className="btn btn-info" to="/">Back To Index</Link>
        <h3>{post.title}</h3>
        <p>{post.content}</p>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

function mapStateToProps({ posts }, ownProps) {
  return { post: posts[ownProps.match.params.id] };
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, { fetchPost })(PostsShow);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
<Route path="/" component={PostsIndex} />
<Route path="/posts/:id" component={PostsShow} />
```

Because `/` also satisfies `/posts/:id`, and you don't want to show both components, make it so the `/` only matches if it's exactly `/`, like so

```
<Route exact path="/" component={PostsIndex} />
<Route path="/posts/:id" component={PostsShow} />
```

One other options is using `react-router`'s [`Switch`](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/Switch) component so that only one of the routes will match. However, you would need to change the order of your routes so that the `/` route is last, like so

```
<Switch>
 <Route path="/posts/:id" component={PostsShow}/>
 <Route path="/" component={PostsIndex}/>
</Switch>
```

Be sure to import `Switch` if you're going to use it.